# multi-store with an sub-directory nginx php-fpm

Tags: multistore, nginx

I have an EC-2 instance on AWS with NGINX and PHP-FPM running Magento 1.9

The need arose to create a multi store system using a sub directory.

mydomain.com = default store
mydomain.com/teen = teen store

How do I set?

Comment: You don't want to do that, Google doesn't index subdirectories very well and you will be penalised - you really want separate tlds. Plus you should swap PHP-FPM with HHVM - you get 5-10x the performance from the same hardware - it's the little secret service providers don't want you to know about - hopefully you are running RDS for low maintenance.

Comment: Nginx /w fpm /w opcache /w redis: I don't think a 5-10 fold increase is realistic. In response time? Processor time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emulate a subdirectory you don't need to actually create a subdirectory on the filesystem. Instead you need to enable the store code in the url in `System > Config > General > Web`:

[image]

Comment: thank you, works good! But, that way I will have problems with modules that use the base url, as paypal and others in the new store?

Comment: No, if the module is coded correctly you should be just fine :)